# Bluetooth key lost when removed windows

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I connected a bluetooth device in windows first. Later I formated the windows partition. Now when I tried to connect the bluetooth device in Ubuntu I am not able to. I came to know we need the key generated in Windows. But I deleted windows from my machine. How can I solve this?

---

**Edit:**

Result of `dmesg |grep -i blue` is

```
[   12.869438] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   12.869456] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.869459] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.869462] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.869468] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.896508] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd failed with error -2
[   12.896513] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd not found
[   14.437557] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   14.437563] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   14.437568] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   14.484529] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   14.484531] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   14.484534] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.901392] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  765.511199] Modules linked in: bnep rfcomm nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core bluetooth v4l2_common videodev media wl(POE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi hp_wmi amdkfd sparse_keymap amd_iommu_v2 radeon intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd joydev serio_raw snd_soc_rt286 cfg80211 snd_soc_core snd_compress i915 snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek lpc_ich snd_hda_codec_generic ttm drm_kms_helper mei_me shpchp mei snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller drm processor_thermal_device snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep i2c_algo_bit wmi snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi int3403_thermal snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer video snd i2c_hid hid dw_dmac soundcore dw_dmac_core snd_soc_sst_acpi i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core hp_wireless spi_pxa2xx_platform int3402_thermal 8250_dw int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid acpi_pad parport_pc ppdev lp parport psmouse ahci r8169 libahci mii sdhci_acpi sdhci
```

---

**Edit 2:**

I added `brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd` file and rebooted. I could connect to my bluetooth speaker but could not play audio. I cant find my speaker in sound settings output.

---

**Edit 3:**
I uninstalled `blueman` and rebooted and it worked.

---

**EDIT 3:**

I dont know why but the sound strucks when played on bluetooth device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the old Windows key. when you re-pair the bluetooth device in Ubuntu, a new key will be generated.

---

If the bluetooth device is not even seen, maybe there is a driver problem - what bluetooth hardware/driver are you using?  Please post the output of:"

```
dmesg |grep -i blue
```

Comment: But I could not find the bluetooth device when I search for devices.

Comment: Added the result `dmesg |grep -i blue  `

Comment: I could connect to bluetooth speaker. But I could not see it in sound settings output